# How to view data from postgres configured for LATIN1 encoding

Tags: postgresql

How to view data from postgres configured for LATIN1 encoding

```
# select foo from bar;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x9c in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"

\encoding
LATIN1

show lc_messages;
 lc_messages 
-------------
 en_US
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the PostgreSQL server that is configured for LATIN-1 (fortunately the server encoding is `UTF8`), it is the client. Character `“` doesn't have a representation in LATIN-1, so you cannot have that.

The only option is to choose a different client encoding. If `UTF8` is not an option, and you need a single-byte encoding on the client, perhaps WINDOWS-1252 would be good enough for you:

```
\encoding WIN1252
```